# Cox PH modeling and prediction with time varying dependency

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have some questions regarding the use of coxph() and predict(Surv()). I am aware that my question is a bit long one and maybe I have not explained myself well enough but any comment or suggestion is appreciated.

I am trying to make a Cox PH model and predictions for roof repair on houses. I have 5 input variables (covariates):

House_Age (also called Start), House_Price, Roof_Material_Grp_New, Land_Ownership_Status_Grp, Living_Status_Grp

As the names suggest the first two are numeric variables and the last three at categorical. My problem is that I want to make the House_Age hazard to be depending on time. I chose to do 'datasplitting' for every third year of House_Age (so House_Age turns into the variable Start) - for instance in the case of an Event happening after 7 years the data would look like

```
Start Stop Event_01_Ts

0    3           0 (Censored)
3    3           0 (Censored)
6    1           1 (Event)
```

Start is equal to the House_Age. As I could see on the estimates of each value of Start group there seemed to a linear dependence until about 40 years so I chose to have a maximum Start/House_Age of 40 and a linear relation

```
Cox_Mod_Lin <- coxph(Surv(Stop,Event_01_Ts) ~ Start+Roof_Material_Grp_New+House_Contract_Yen+Land_Ownership_Status_Grp+Living_Status_Grp,data=Abt_Roof_Ts_Mdl)
```

The model comes out fine with linear coefficient on the Start variable on 0.1916 and an exponential value of 1.211
                                  coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)       z Pr(>|z|)
Start                        1.916e-01  1.211e+00  6.817e-03  28.112  < 2e-16 ***

Looking on the Start/House_Age isolated, the hazard increases by 21% each year - is the correct? My problem is that now I want to make predicitons of 'repair' probabilities whitin 1, 5 and 10 years for instance. First I try to find the baseline hazard function by using survfit and a zero-vector as input

```
Base <- survfit(Cox_Mod_Lin,Abt_Baseline,type='aalen')
Base_Time_Hz <- as.data.frame(cbind(Base$time,Base$cumhaz))
Base_Time_Hz_1yr <- Base_Time_Hz[which(Base_Time_Hz$Time==1),]
```

Here Abt_Baseline contains zeroes for numerical variables and zero-level group values for groups. From this I find the cumulative hazard for time=1, 5 and 10 (only 1 year is shown) and multiply this with the exponential of the "lp" prediction found by using the predict function.

One year prediction:

```
Pred_01<-Base_Time_Hz_1yr$Cumhaz*exp(predict(Cox_Mod_Lin,Abt_Roof_Score, type="lp"))
```

This would be OK if there were no time dependent inputs but the hazard varies in the future as a function of the Start (=House_Age) variable. I know the future values of the Start (increase by 1 each year) so I suppose that I could integrate somehow over the prediction period. So I have two main questions:

- Does this seem to be a sensible way for doing the modeling and (some of) the prediction?
- If yes - how do I do the integration over the prediction period with with respect to the varying (increasing) House_Age/Start hazard?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The modelling part seems sensible to me, but not the prediction part. I don't think you need the baseline hazard. I'd suggest you take a look at the `predictSurvProb` function in the `pec` package. This function makes predictions for new data based on your coxph model for a given point in time (e.g. 1, 5, 10 year).

Comment: Also take a look at  <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Greg/vignettes/timeSplitter.html> for how to adjust your data to be able to make predictions in the case of time varying covariates. [You probably won't use the timeSplitter function he is talking about, but the logic is the same]

Comment: Thanks a lot MarcelG. I was not too sure of the prediction part myself. I will have a look at your suggestions.

Comment: I have one more question to you @MarcelG. Thanks to the predictSurvProb function I was able to predict the survival probability one year ahead. So what I did was time splitting the data that I wanted to predict so I had - for each house - one line for each year in the future (10 years ahead) with corresponding values of House_Age (1 year older each year) and the rest of the input variables constant. I found the one-year-ahead-probability for each year (by predictSurvProb) and in order to find the probability after 10 years I multiplied the probabilities for each year. Does this sound sensible?

Comment: It seems sensible, but I can't give you a definite answer. However, follow my line of reasoning. Suppose you have a house of 10 years old. You now predicted the survival probability for 1 year for a 10, 11, .., 19 years old house (all else equal), and multiplied those probabilities. Suppose we are at time t and the time of Death is D, you basically calculated the chances P(D > t + 1 | House_Age). If the house is 19 years old, the probability must be P(D > t + 10 | D > t + 9, House_Age) = (?) P(D > t + 1 | House_Age). Therefore it seems sensible to me, however i am not sure (see the ?)

Comment: @MarcelG - once again thank you very much it has been very useful for me. I am not sure I understand your formula - I think would write it like this:  P(D>t|House_Age) = P(D>1|House_Age)*P(D>1|House_Age+1)* ... *P(D>1|House_Age+(t-1)). Maybe it is the same as you say. I am new to R and survival models and I am a bit surprised that it has been hard to find examples with predictions for breakdown where the hazard depends on the age. I would think that this is a normal problem but maybe I searched the wrong places (Cox PH models), maybe there are more suited models.

Comment: In my formula I assumed we are at point in time _t_. However, in survival analysis we always start at time _0_ (so my bad). Furthermore, I meant the same thing as you said so sorry for being unclear.

Comment: To comment on your remark that its hard to find examples. Yes, very true. Prediction with time-varying covariates in Cox PH models are very very sparse. I worked with these models during my thesis. However, it is possible but very tedious (as you already noticed). If you are considering other models, try ATF (Accelerated Time Failure) models.

Comment: Thanks again @MarcelG. Yes, this is bit more 'messy' than ordinary linear regression, someone should have warned me. I will have a look at the Accelerated Time Failure models - I saw them mentioned somewhere, sounds like they might be easier to use than all this multiplication trouble.

Comment: Good luck! I just noticed that another error of me. It is an AFT model not ATF ;)